# About django, each user information save to database

Tags: django

I want to save the database attendance data daily of each user,

but my no error no saved why? please help me
this is my full code below:

this is my views.py:

```
def staffs(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['staffs'] = User.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("staffs.html", args)

def staffdetail(request, user_id=1):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    return render_to_response("staffdetail.html",
                         {"user": User.objects.get(id=user_id) })

def attendance(request, user_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        attendance = Attendance_data(user = request.user.id)
        form = AttendancekForm(request.POST, instance = attendance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/get/%s' % user.id)
    else:
        form = AttendanceForm()
    return render_to_response('attendance.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))

def leave_work(request, user_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        leave_work = Leave_work(user = request.user.id)
        form = Leave_workForm(request.POST, instance = leave_work)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/articles/get/%s' % user.id)
    else:
        form = Leave_workForm()
    return render_to_response('leave.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

So,i'm also add my models.py and forms.py here
this is my models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_kana = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_kana  = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    employee_number = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=22)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name

class Attendance_data(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    employee_number = models.CharField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name, employee_number

class Leave_work(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    employee_number = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=22)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name, employee_unmber
```

this is my forms.py:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('user_name','first_kana', 'last_kana', 'employee_number')
    user_name = forms.CharField( label="name",error_messages={'required': ''})
    first_kana = forms.CharField(label="firstname",error_messages={'required': ''})
    last_kana = forms.CharField(label="lastname",error_messages={'required': ''})
    employee_number = forms.CharField(label="number", required=False)

class Attendance_dataForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance_data
        fields = ('user_name','employee_number')

    user_name = forms.CharField(label="name", error_messages={'required': ''})
    employee_number = forms.CharField(label="number",error_messages={'required': ''})

class Leave_workForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Leave_work
        fields = ('user_name', 'employee_number')
    user_name = forms.CharField(label="name", error_messages={'required': ''})
    employee_number = forms.CharField(label="number", error_messages={'required': ''})
```

Comment: post your error what you facing ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of wrong thing in your views. If you look at your model `Attendence_data`, it has two fields user_name and employee_number. so its constructor would accept two arguments, `user_name` and `employee_number` or any other fields that are set not to be NULL and have no default value, so passing request.user.id to the its constructor would not make it a valid object. Same is the case with `Leave_work` model. So if you need to do this, you need to overload the default constructor. 
But seems like you are not being able to understand the basic concepts of how Django works so  I'd suggest you to go trough [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/%E2%80%8E) tutorial as this will clear a lot of basic concepts.

Comment: and what is the argument `work` that you are passing to the instance parameter of the `AttendenceForm` constructor.

Comment: I don't know should I write way

Comment: >>form = AttendancekForm(request.POST, instance = work) this is a mistake to write, It was corrected to attendance, but can not be saved

Comment: And also the the code that defines the AttendenceForm

Comment: This is the tutorial link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ that @Darwesh mentioned.